# Postgresql Relation ID

Tags: postgresql, transactional-replication, postgresql-10

I'm trying to utilze Postgres 10 [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html) mechanism by reading replication messages in Go code. Most of the logical [replication messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html) refer to something called "Relation Id".

My question is: how to get Relation Ids for all of the existing tables? I am aware of "Relation" message type, but I don't know how to trigger them.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I assume that's the relation's [`oid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html)

Comment: Yes, it is. However I found out that I wanted to do it wrong way. I shouldn't load relations by myself. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/protocol-logical-replication.html#PROTOCOL-LOGICAL-MESSAGES-FLOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using logical replication publisher sends [`Relation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html) messages before sending the data, which contain all information necessary to decode incoming messages. Thus reading database schema beforehand would be not the right way of getting `RelationID`.

[This](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/protocol-logical-replication.html#PROTOCOL-LOGICAL-MESSAGES-FLOW) was the documentation page I was missing.